# Rewrite 404-ing feed pages in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, catch-all

Sorry if the title was a bit vague.  We've recently changed the WordPress theme of our site and it looks like the old theme created an RSS feed for every single page.  These are now 404-ing, and I was wondering if I could fix this in .htaccess?  An example URL which is now not found is:

www.example.com/page-name/feed

I would like it to redirect to

www.example.com/page-name/

Can I do a catch-all for these?  There's over 100 variations of 'page-name'.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in /.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/feed$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

It does this:

```
http://www.example.com/page-ink/feed =>  http://www.example.com/page-ink/
http://www.example.com/1258/feed =>  http://www.example.com/1258/
...
```